# Zip file corrupted after SSH file transfer

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssh, zip

I'm trying to zip up some files on my Windows laptop, then transfer them to my Ubuntu server, and unzip them there, but I always get an error while unzipping the archive telling me that the archive is corrupt.

I've done some checks, and though the zip files have the same filesize, the SHA256 checksum is different after transferring the files.

I used the following command (on my Windows laptop with using PowerShell):

```
cat .\archive.zip | ssh user@address "cat > ~/archive.zip"
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the difference in operating systems, maybe the different line endings. Does anyone know how I can transfer the archive properly?

Comment: Do the files have *exactly* the same size, to the byte?

Comment: No, I just saw there is about a 200 bytes difference. The file on the server is bigger.

Comment: It could be that `cat` is changing individual occurrences of LF and CR to the sequence CRLF because it is intended for text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to use SFTP, and that did transfer the file correctly. I'd still like to know why cat over ssh doesn't work and if this is possible without SFTP, though.

Comment: Most likely this is related to line ending differences between POSIX and Windows.  Another good tool to learn is scp , which uses ssh as its basis.

Comment: The reason, as described in [another answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1491144/edit), is because in Powershell `cat` isn't really `cat ` at all, it's a wrapper around a line-oriented tool

Answer (score 3):

One of the comments under the question:

> It could be that `cat` is changing individual occurrences of `LF` and `CR` to the sequence `CRLF` because it is intended for text.

Real cats are too lazy for this sh… shenanigan. In PowerShell `cat` is an alias for `Get-Content`. You need few parameters to make it behave like a nice `cat`.

> Example 6: Get raw content
>
> The commands in this example get the contents of a file as one string, instead of an array of strings. By default, without the `Raw` dynamic parameter, content is returned as an array of newline-delimited strings. […]
>
> ```
> $raw = Get-Content -Path .\LineNumbers.txt -Raw
> ```

I guess in your case this "array of newline-delimited strings" was concatenated and some monkey business with line endings occurred. But even with `Raw` you will still get a string. You don't want a string.

> Example 8: Get file contents as a byte array
>
> This example demonstrates how to get the contents of a file as a `[byte[]]` as a single object.
>
> ```
> $byteArray = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\test.txt -AsByteStream -Raw
> ```
>
> […]
>
> The first command uses the `AsByteStream` parameter to get the stream of bytes from the file. The `Raw` parameter ensures that the bytes are returned as a `[System.Byte[]]`. If the `Raw` parameter was absent, the return value is a stream of bytes, which is interpreted by PowerShell as `[System.Object[]]`.

<sup>([source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6))</sup>

I don't know PowerShell at all. I don't know if you should want `[System.Byte[]]` or `[System.Object[]]`, or if it matters at all in your case. I found [this statement](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/65560526-get-content-topic-explain-the-relationship-between-raw-and-asbytestream-encoding-byte):

> Combining `-Raw` with `-AsByteStream` / `-Encoding Byte` is actually the simplest way to get the file's content as a raw byte array (`[byte[]]`), output as a single object (as opposed to the bytes streaming one by one, in the absence of `-Raw`).

I *guess* probably you should use `Raw`. I'm certain you should use `AsByteStream`.